# Changing application setting in Unit test

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, settings

I have created a unit test in a separate project.  I am trying to change a filepath I have as a  setting in the main project.  I access the path as `My.Settings.FooBarPath`.  I can't figure out how to change it in my unit test. How do I access the settings in my main project from the unit test project and how do I change the values?

I have read this post: [Modifying application settings in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719107/modifying-application-settings-in-unit-tests)

The second answer seemed to be the most useful but I couldn't quite seem to get it to work for my unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to modify the settings.xml file manually. It's a bit convoluted, but this tutorial might help for saving and loading text files into your app (of course you'd do it without a UI) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3nSXaD2J9Q

Another option is to start up your other program with `Shell()` and have a command line argument for the setting to change and what to change it to.

Answer (score 0):

The question asked was for VB.Net while the answer given in [Modifying application settings in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719107/modifying-application-settings-in-unit-tests) is for C#. As I had the same question for VB.Net I thought I'd give a VB.Net version of the answer here. Based on the C# answer I got this to work in my project (using Visual Studio 2013) with the following:

1. The test project should be correctly set up as a unit test for the application under test ("[Create and run unit tests](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/create-and-run-unit-tests-vs)" should help in setting it up correctly)
2. using the fully qualified namespace of the application under test `myprojects_namespace.My.settings`
   will give you full (intellisense powered) access to the user settings of the application under test.

After that you can read / write to the user settings as you would normally do.
e.g.

```
myprojects_namespace.My.settings.someProperty = "somevalue"
Assert.AreEqual("somevalue", myprojects_namespace.My.settings.someProperty)
```

P.S.: I didn't need to add anything in my `AssemblyInfo.vb` file. There is no reference to `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo` as this seems to already have been handled by setting up the unit test project correctly for the application under test.

Comment: OK, somehow this doesn't work after all... 
I'm trying to get the current values (in my case these are user settings)
I get the values set at design time but not the user settings current values
... it's back to the drawing board I'm afraid ...